# Exploiting ordering to removing infeasible solutions in MILP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, branch-and-cut, cutting-planes, valid-inequalities

I kindly ask for some ideas or references to exploit ordering in MILPs.

In particular, there are resources $ r = [r_1, r_2, ..., r_K] $ such that $r_{i} \leq r_{i+1} $. These are input to the problem.

In addition, there are binary variables $ x = [x_1, x_2, ..., x_K] $ such that $ \sum_i x_i = 1 $  used to select the resources. Besides, there are also continuous-valued variables $y$ in a convex set $ \Omega $.

The objective is $ \max_{x,y} \sum_i u_i x_i $ where $ u = [u_1, u_2, ..., u_K] $, $u_{i} \leq u_{i+1} $ represent utility.

My problem looks like this:

$$ \max_{x,y} \sum_i u_i x_i
\\
g_m(y) \geq  \sum_i r_i x_i, m = 1, \dots, M,
\\
\sum_i x_i = 1,
\\
y \in \Omega,
$$.

One can see that selecting $ x_{i+1} = 1 $ may generate better objectives than $ x_{i} = 1 $.

I would like to exploit the fact that $r_i$ are ordered. For instance, if allocating $ r_j $ does not yield a feasible solution, then it makes no sense to try with $ r_{j+1} $. I am using MOSEK and GUROBI to solve this problem, and I understand that this kind of structure is very particular to my problem and perhaps not exploited by these solvers. I have randomly changed the order of the elements in $ r $ and $ u $ (keeping the one-to-one correspondence) and I get comparable execution times.

Is it possible to add cuts that exploit this structure and reduce the number of evaluations (branches)? I would be very grateful!

**Example**:

$ r = [0.5, 2.1, 3.7, 5.1] $

$ u = [9.8, 12.5, 18.1, 25.2] $

$ x = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4] $

$ y \in \Omega (convex) $

$$ \max_{x,y} \sum_i 9.8 x_1 +  12.5 x_2 + 18.1 x_3 + 25.2 x_4
\\
g (y) \geq  0.5 x_1 + 2.1 x_2 + 3.7x_3 + 5.1 x_4,
\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1,
\\
y \in \Omega,
$$.

As explained above, if $ x_2 = 1 $ is not feasible, that means that $ g (y) \geq 2.1 $ cannot be satisfied. Thus, evaluating $ x_3 = 1 $, $ x_4 = 1 $ is not necessary due to the sorted strcuture of $ r $. Instead, $ x_1 = 1 $ should be evaluated. I would like to add a constraint that considers this to reduce the number of evalautions.

Comment: You could also try the following. 1. Select $i$ with largest $u_i$. 2. If  the problem $\{r_i \le g_m(y) \; \forall m, y\in \Omega \}$ is feasible, you are done, else, try the next largest $i$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set

Comment: @Kuifje thanks for your reply. The problem is more complicated than shown herein. Keeping track of all variables makes it somewhat difficult. I am looking for something more systematic.

Comment: Would you please, try clarifying your problem with a simple numerical example?

Comment: @A.Omidi I have added an example.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the solver used, you may be able to prioritize the $x$ variables so that variables with higher indices are branched on before variables with lower indices (and elements of $x$ are branched on before any other integer variables). You may also be able to instruct the solver, after branching on $x_i$, to prioritize the child with $x_i=1$ over the child with $x_i=0$. Either or both of those may (or may not) speed things up.

Comment: I think this is more or less what I had in mind. But, I am unsure if I can affect the branching process. Once, I execute the program, it will not stop until returning a solution or unitl the maximum runtime is reached. That is why I was wondering if this could be done by adding cuts to the problem.

Comment: Adding cuts does not change the fact that the program will run until it proves optimality or hits a time/memory/iteration limit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I am aiming to reduce the time to solve the problem (optimally). Sometimes adding cuts helps to tighthen the search space but also adds more constraints. I believe that the sorted structure of $ r $ can be exploited by including constraints that depicts that sorted structure but probably that requires more thought.

Comment: What can you say about $g()$ (convex, linear, ...) and $\Omega$ (polyhedral, defined by explicit linear constraints, ...)? If $g()$ is nonlinear and/or $\Omega$ is not polyhedral, you may be able to add cuts on the fly to tighten the LP relaxations.